# Why you have to maintain "S" speed in a320 circuits after a climb?

Tags: airbus-a320

I've been told that in circuits, after reaching thrust acceleration altitude , you should maintain S speed, after a flaps 1 take off? why is it so? why that particular speed. please explain

Comment: Are you flying the whole circuit in config 1?

Comment: Yes cfg 1 @Bianfable

Comment: S-speed gives good maneuvering margins without being too fast which would make the turns too wide for a close pattern. S-speed automatically adjusts for current aircraft weight, so it decreases the work load to just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When flying in clean configuration, the **Green Dot (GD)** speed is the recommended speed for approach and holding<sup>1</sup> because

1. it provides sufficient maneuvering margin:

   > Deviating below GD involves an increase in the drag on the aircraft and would eventually undermine the aircraft’s ability to continue a climb. [...]
   >
   > Therefore in the clean configuration, the crew should not fly below GD in order to avoid degrading climb performance.

   <sup>([Airbus Safety First - Control your speed… during climb](https://safetyfirst.airbus.com/control-your-speed-during-climb/))</sup>
2. it minimizes fuel consumption:

   > GD speed is the managed speed target in CONF CLEAN when the FMS approach phase is activated. It is also the recommended speed to extend flaps to CONF 1 and for a holding in clean configuration. [...]
   >
   > In some phases of flight, GD is computed to minimize drag and thus, the fuel consumption (for example during the HOLD phase).

   <sup>([Airbus Safety First - Control your Speed… During Descent, Approach and Landing](https://safetyfirst.airbus.com/control-your-speed-during-descent-approach-and-landing/))</sup>

However, you said you are flying the circuits in CONF 1 (slats extended). GD speed is replaced by **S Speed** in CONF 1 (and 1+F). Similarly, **F Speed** is used for CONF 2 and 3.

> In approach phase, S speed is the managed speed target, when in CONF 1 or 1+F. It is the recommended speed to select CONF 2.

<sup>([Airbus Safety First - Control your Speed… During Descent, Approach and Landing](https://safetyfirst.airbus.com/control-your-speed-during-descent-approach-and-landing/))</sup>

The FCTM also recommends flying holding patterns in CONF 1 at **S Speed**:

> **HOLDING SPEED AND CONFIGURATION**
>
> If a hold is to be flown, provided NAV mode is engaged and the speed is managed, an
> automatic speed reduction will occur to achieve the Maximum Endurance speed when
> entering the holding pattern. The Maximum Endurance speed is approximately equal to
> Green Dot and provides the lowest hourly fuel consumption.
>
> If the Maximum Endurance speed is greater than the ICAO or state maximum holding
> speed, the crew should select **flap 1** below 20 000 ft and **fly S speed**.

<sup>(Airbus A320 FCTM - Normal Operations - Holding, emphasis mine)</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Circuits aren't mentioned in the manuals I have, but they are operationally similar to holding and approach phase.